# Unable to make Power BI api call from Custom Power BI visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-api

When attempting to make a call, I encountered errors related to Cross-Site Scripting Protection (CSP) and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Please someone help me making it happen.
Thank you.